# Unable to upload images with AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I am trying to upload multiple files (images) with AFHTTPSessionManager but the request is failing with Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)".

Here is my Code.

```
NSString *urlString = [BaseUrl stringByAppendingString:UploadImages];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
NSString *apiKey = [[Utility sharedInstance] getObjectForKey:API_KEY];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:apiKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[manager POST:urlString parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData){

    for(int i = 0 ;i < pictures.count; i++){
        UIImage *image = [pictures objectAtIndex:i];
        NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file%d",i] fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file%d.jpg",i] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }

}progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject){
    NSLog(@"Pictures Uploaded");
}failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Uploading failed %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

Failure:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x14803b080> { URL: https://BaseUrl/v1/imgupload } { status code: 500, headers {
Connection = close;
"Content-Length" = 0;
"Content-Type" = "text/html";
Date = "Thu, 16 Jun 2016 09:25:43 GMT";
Server = "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)";
"X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14";
 } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://BaseUrl/v1/imgupload, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500)}
```

Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong.Thanks

Comment: As error states its most likely a server error and not an issue with your code, Also when in doubt use postman

Comment: Yup internal server error 500 is caused when there is issue with server, like the when server is down or not available

Comment: The server is not down.Working fine in postman but not with AFNetworking.

Comment: I think its same failure show me,  then send png image then its success,

Answer (score 0):

Change your code my for loop instead of your for loop,

```
for(int i = 0 ;i < pictures.count; i++){
        UIImage *imag = [pictures objectAtIndex:i];
        NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation (imag);
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"Photo" fileName:@"Image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
    }
```

Name, fileName is not important, its stored image some id, so its not important, its simply give default values.

hope its helpful

Comment: Yes it's important.Using your for loop uploads only one image.